# VB.net add css class to clicked element

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to add CssClass to clicked element?

```
Protected Sub ShowButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowButton.Click

    // Add "active" CssClass to ShowButton 

End Sub
```

Is it possible to reference to element by `this` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sender` parameter is referring to the control which triggered this method (ie: the *sender* of the event).

Therefore you can change the properties of this object.

Assming `ShowButton` is a `Button` control. If not, change `Button` to whatever the type of the control is:

```
Protected Sub ShowButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowButton.Click

    CType(sender, Button).CssClass = "active" 

End Sub
```

---

If your control only has the one class, you can easily remove it by doing the following:

```
CType(sender, Button).CssClass = ""
```

However, if you have multiple classes it can get more complicated. You could do:

```
CType(sender, Button).CssClass = CType(sender, Button).CssClass.Replace("active", "")
```

This only replaces `active` in the `CssClass` string property with a blank string. This works fine unless you have a class like `reactive` as well. This would then be changed to `re`.

Comment: Great! Can you remove specific class from the element? If yes, how?